# Results of Linq to datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I am trying to do a left outer join of 2 datatables using Linq. I want the results of the join back in another datatable. But I am unable to turn the results of LINQ to a datatable. Any help is appreciated. I think I have the LINQ part correct.

```
Dim dtSourceTB As DataTable
Dim vSourceTBSQL As New Text.StringBuilder

vSourceTBSQL.AppendLine("SELECT * FROM TRIAL_BALANCE_F ")
vSourceTBSQL.AppendLine("WHERE PERIOD_NAME = 'JUN-22' ")

    dtSourceTB = ExecuteSql(dbConnSourceTB, vSourceTBSQL.ToString, True)

Dim dtTargetTB As DataTable
Dim vTargetTBSQL As New Text.StringBuilder

vTargetTBSQL.AppendLine("select * from  ReconBalance ")
vTargetTBSQL.AppendLine("Where  PERIOD_NAME = 'JUN-22' ")

    dtTargetTB = ExecuteSql(DbConnTarget, vTargetTBSQL.ToString, True)    

Dim Results  =  From SF In dtSourceTB
        Group Join OS In dtTargetTB
        On SF.Field(Of String)("SEGMENT_COMB") Equals OS.Field(Of String)("SEGMENT_COMB")
        Into Group 
        From OS In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
        Select  Entity = SF.Field(Of String)("Entity"),
        Account = SF.Field(Of String)("Account"),
        Country = SF.Field(Of String)("Country"),
        ReconcilingPeriod = OS.Field(Of String)("ReconcilingPeriod"),
        Required = OS.Field(Of String)("Required"),
        SourceTB = SF.Field(Of String)("ENDING_BALANCE"),
        TargetTB = OS.Field(Of String)("Balance"),
        SegmentComb = SF.Field(Of String)("SEGMENT_COMB")
```

Comment: There are a number of Nuget packages that will do this, including LinqToDataTable https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToDataTable

Comment: Is `Results` Nothing or is there a rowcount?  It sounds like you expect this code to copy data into table `ReconBalance`, but it isn't getting there.

Answer (score 0):

What I don't understand is why don't you run the SQL in the first place to fill the DataTable from a DataAdapter? No need for LINQ at all.

```vb
Dim sql = "
    SELECT
        TrialBalance.Entity,
        TrialBalance.Account,    
        TrialBalance.Country,
        ReconBalance.ReconcilingPeriod,
        ReconBalance.Required,    
        TrialBalance.ENDING_BALANCE AS EndingBalance,
        ReconBalance.Balance,    
        TrialBalance.SEGMENT_COMB AS SegmentComb
    FROM
        TRIAL_BALANCE_F AS TrialBalance
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ReconBalance ON TrialBalance.SEGMENT_COMB = ReconBalance.SEGMENT_COMB
    WHERE
        TrialBalance.PERIOD_NAME = 'JUN-22';
"

Dim results = New DataTable()
Try
    Using con = New SqlConnection("my connection string here")
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                adapter.Fill(results)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    ' do something with the exception
End Try
```

Comment: I can't use SQL. They both are in different systems and I am pulling the data in a 3rd system. So I can't join those 2 tables other than writing a code in the 3rd system.